# String array returns null pointer exception

Tags: java, string, pointers, exception, null

```
a=10.00;
b=11.00;
mor_names=new String[]{};   
for(double cal=Double.parseDouble(a);cal<=Double.parseDouble(b);) {
    mor_names[val]=(Double.toString(cal));
    System.out.println("values are:" + mor_names[val]);
    val++;
    cal=cal+0.15;
}
```

I try to add a value to string array but it raises a null pointer exception, why?

**EDIT 1:**

```
DateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
try
{
    timefrom =(Time) time.parse(json.get(position).toString());
    timeto = (Time) time.parse(json.get(position).toString());
} 
catch (ParseException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

System.out.println("times are :"+timefrom+" "+timeto+" "+position);//null null 0 was output for this

for(Time i=timefrom;i.equals(timeto);)
{
    cal.setTime(i);
    System.out.println("values are:" + i);
    mor_names[val]=(String) i.toString();
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
    System.out.println("values are:" + mor_names[val]);
    String newTime = df.format(cal.getTime());
    try
    {
        i=new java.sql.Time(time.parse(newTime).getTime());
    } 
    catch (ParseException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    val++;
}
```

I tried to get a date in particular time gap so I am trying to sink with java calendar and manipulate my code but possibly I cant get it right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Where is `val` declared? In Java arrays are not dynamically growable. You have declare 0 size array.

Comment: what is a and b variable Type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's review your code:

```
a=10.00;
b=11.00;
```

From that we can assume that `a` and `b` are type of `Double`, so you can't use `double cal = Double.parseDouble(a)` to get a `double` value. This would be correct if `a` and `b` was of type `String`:

```
String a="10.00";
String b="11.00";
```

The next line:

```
mor_names=new String[]{};
```

will initialize the **empty** array of Strings. The `{}` parentheses are used with arrays like so to initialize array with values:

```
String[] mor_names = {"Hello", "World", "!"};
```

and this is the same like:

```
String[] mor_names = new String[]{"Hello", "World", "!"};
```

You want to assign values to array, so you could initialize your array like that:

```
String[] mor_names = new String[7]{};
```

with that you can't store more values in `mor_names` than 7 with indexes from 0 to 6.

If you want more flexible approach use `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<String> mor_names = new ArrayList<String>();
```

this will create a "dynamic array" where you can `add`, `remove` and `get` your `String` objects.

Loop for:

```
for(double cal = Double.parseDouble(a) ; cal<=Double.parseDouble(b) ; )
```

Lets fix one thing just like we mentioned before, assuming that `a` and `b` are type of `double`.

```
for(double cal = a ; cal <= b ; )
```

First, `cal` variable is initialized with value of `a`. For is a loop and it will repeat code between `{}` parentheses until `cal <= b` is true. You are incrementing `cal` value inside this loop, but that is unnecessary - you can do it like this:

```
for(double cal = a ; cal <= b ; cal+=0.15)
```

That means that each time the code inside loop has been executed to the end, `cal` will be incremented by `0.15`. Then if `cal` is less or equal `b` the code will repeat. Otherwise the loop will end.

`NullPointerException` would rise if you are trying to assign `String` value to uninitialized array. But that is not what is happening here, because `mor_names` is not `null`.

You should read about initializing variables and using arrays and containers in java. Good luck.

**EDIT 1:**

You are giving incomplete data. You should provide all things that makes your question solid, especially strict and specific description of what you are trying to archive.

Read about [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java) and [Java - Date & Time](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_date_time.htm). Use google and read with understanding.

Also about using stack**overflow** you should start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

One more time, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
String a="10.00";
String b="11.00";
int val=0;
String [] mor_names=new String[10];
for(double cal=Double.parseDouble(a); cal<=Double.parseDouble(b);){
   mor_names[val]=(Double.toString(cal));
   System.out.println("values are:" + mor_names[val]);
   val++;
   cal=cal+0.15;
}
```

you can use this code.if you want dynamic string array,you should use list or map.

Comment: Before posting your answer look at `Preview` and make sure that your indentation is correct.